# Is there a way to make __filename and __dirname global in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a number of files which use these values __dirname and __filename. Unfortunately, I run into problems that the variables have aready been declared especially when I run Jest test. I solved that issue temporarily but a certain test is causing this to break. My goal is to make this piece of code global. My attempt at reuse is shown below. It works for the most part but fails because of some jest tests.

```js
                import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
                import  path  from 'path'; 

                const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
                const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

                export{ __filename, __dirname)
```

Then I use it like this

```js
               const{ __filename, __dirname) = FileVals
```

Is there a way to make this global so it is visible everywhere it is needed?

Comment: No, this is not possible. A global variable would have the same value everywhere. You need to put that code in every file itself.

Comment: You can switch to CommonJS, as those are built-ins